# 2 BMS in Parallel connected to 2 batteries in series

Tags: batteries, charging, series, bms

This circuit is for charging the two batteries only.  The LED board will run on 3.7 volts, but 7-8 volts does not affect the function of the LED board.  With this circuit, the LEDs will stay bright even as the batteries voltages drop down to around 2 volts each or even lower, where the BMS boards would shut down the batteries while they are still able to power the LED board.

I believe I could change the the two 1S BMS boards with one 2S BMS board and get the same results, but my space is very limited, and the 1S boards are much smaller than the 2S boards.  The LED board draws very little current, so I don't think I need battery protection on batteries when power is being drawn.[image]